# meteor iterate over a set of Sessions to check if the value have changed

Tags: javascript, session, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, iteration

I got those Sessions:

```
Session.set("group_name",false);
Session.set("group_date",false);
Session.set("group_friends",false);
Session.set("group_location",false);
Session.set("group_rules",false);
Session.set("group_desc",false);
Session.set("group_save",false);
```

I'm using bootstrap progress bar, which only needs width property to be change.
I'm trying to achieve an action similar to Session.get, meaning I want to check if something changed in one of those Sessions so I can increment the width of the progress bar.
I have tried doing something like that:

```
Meteor.render(function(){
    prog = 0 ;
    prog = prog;
    for( var i in Session.keys){
        if(Session.keys.hasOwnProperty(i) && Session.keys[i] != "false"){
            prog  = prog + 1*15;
        }
    }
    return console.log(prog);
});
```

my HTML:

```
<div class="bar" style="width: {{prog}}%;">
```

That's not working. I'm missing something but I don't know what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not all that familiar with `Meteor.render`, but from the docs it returns a reactive fragment which would then need to be appended to the DOM. I'm guessing that's why its not working. That being said, you really don't need to call `Meteor.render` directly (probably ever). You can do this just with templates and helpers. Here is a complete working example:

#### test.html

```
<body>
  {{> test}}
</body>

<template name="test">
  <div id='progress-wrapper'>
    <div id='progress' style='width: {{progress}}%;'></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

#### test.js

```
var PROGRESS_VARS = ['group_name', 'group_date', 'group_friends',
'group_location', 'group_rules', 'group_desc', 'group_save'];

Template.test.created = function() {
  _.each(PROGRESS_VARS, function(p) {
    Session.set(p, false);
  });
};

Template.test.helpers({
  progress: function() {
    var total = 0;
    var length = PROGRESS_VARS.length;

    _.each(PROGRESS_VARS, function(p) {
      if (Session.get(p)) {
        total += 1;
      }
    });

    return Math.ceil(100 * total / length);
  }
});
```

#### test.css

```
#progress-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 50%;
}
#progress {
  background-color: #008000;
  height: 50px;
}
```